How do I update date modified to now in finder?
I want to update the modified time of a file in finder, just like touch a.txt, how do I do it?

Why not just use the touch command? What problem are you trying to solve?

I don't know why you want to do this, but you could use a Quick Action (touch command wrapped in Automator) to put touch in the Finder context menu.

@Gilby or someone that knows how to do this, let’s link to a duplicate question or post this as a proper answer?

If @Gilbys post a proper answer, I would be willing to delete my answer_.

@DavidAnderson Any "proper" answer would just duplicate your 3 year old answer. Your answer below is fine by me (and upvoted).

As user Gilby has already stated in the comment, you could create a Quick Action. The steps for creating a Quick Action for a different question are given in this answer. You would need to make the following changes.

Step 4 shows the following.
opendiff "$@"

In your case, the above command should be replaced with the command given below.
touch "$@"


In steps 5 and 6, use Touch instead of Compare.



To update the modified time of a file in Finder on macOS, open Terminal, navigate to the file's directory using cd, and then use the touch command followed by the file name (e.g., touch a.txt). This will set the file's modification time to the current date and time.

Isn't that rather a Terminal solution? The OP wants to do it in Finder ("like touch foo.bar").

That's right. Sorry.
Select the file in Finder, right-click, and choose "Get Info" (or press Command + I). In the Info window that appears, locate the "Modified" section, click on the current date and time, and update it to the current date and time. Close the Info window, and the file's modified time will be updated accordingly. Here's a direct solution.

Please amend your answer if you have a method that fulfils the question. Somehow I think you've not tested this.

Did you actually try the Get Info approach? I wasn‘t able to update anything in the General and More Info sections.
